# C - É possível inserir uma matriz numa estrutura?

Tags: c, matriz

Uma dúvida que me surgiu à dias, era se é possível inserir uma matriz numa estrutura, eu acho que sim, mas na via das dúvidas decidi esclarecer.

**EXEMPLO**

```
typedef struct matrizexemplo {
    int matriz[2][2];
}
```

Comment: Possível é, está tendo algum problema?

Comment: ah olá @bigown novamente! era um problema de uma amiga minha, mas já resolveu o assunto, obrigado na mesma! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perfeitamente possível. Segue um exemplo de utilização para somar dois elementos dessa matriz:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct matriz{
    int matriz[2][2];
}Matriz;

int main() {
    Matriz uma_matriz;

    uma_matriz.matriz[0][0] = 1;
    uma_matriz.matriz[1][1] = 2;

    // Printa 3 no terminal
    printf("%d\n", uma_matriz.matriz[0][0] + uma_matriz.matriz[1][1]);

    return 0;
}
```